# How do I properly create a BufferedImage from file?

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

I have this code:

```
package test;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class SwingSandbox {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        JFrame frame = buildFrame();

        final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Projects\\Test\\src\\test\\InterestCalcGraphic.jpg"));

        JPanel pane = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };


        frame.add(pane);
    }


    private static JFrame buildFrame() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        return frame;
    }


}
```

When I run it, I get this error message:

```
    Exception in thread "main" javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
    at test.SwingSandbox.main(SwingSandbox.java:17)
```

The error message leads me to believe that my file path is incorrect, but the image is stored under Test - src - test    in my file directory. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5713096/javax-imageio-iioexception-for-apparently-no-reason

Comment: The image can't be read for some reason, maybe it doesn't exist or is not a supported image format

Comment: It exists, because it shows up in the file directory, and how could jpgs not be supported?

Comment: Is there any cause exception in stack trace?

Comment: No. The only error is the one I posted.

Comment: don't do everything in one line.  try:
File myFile = new File ("C:\......e);
String myFilePath = myFile.getAbsolutePath();
System.out.println ("myFilePath = " + myFilePath);

Also see what the method File.canRead() gives you.
And if all that works then try ImageIO.read

Comment: I tried that, and I still get the same error message.

Comment: Attach your image, please. It's either the path that is incorrect, or the image is unreadable.

Comment: I can't attach any images to stackoverflow, because my computer screen isn't big enough to fir the entire add image popup.

Comment: Try using `ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("new "/test/InterestCalcGraphic.jpg"));`, never, ever, use a path reference which includes `src`, these files won't exist when the program is packaged.

Comment: and why am I able to reaed this??     try {      bim=ImageIO.read(new File("c:/vision/src/yel.png"));    } - that "never, ever" is on the dumpsters then

Comment: Voting to close, as this is just a path typo.

Answer (score 3):

I created a folder called graphics, and then used just the folder name in my path, nothing else. Like this:

```
final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("graphics/a.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 1):

ImageIO hasn't even tried to load your image file. Something is wrong with your file itself. E.g. your path is incorrect. Try to call this

```
File f = new File("C:\\Projects\\Test\\src\\test\\InterestCalcGraphic.jpg");
boolean value = f.canRead();
```

What is boolean value of `value` variable? If it `false` check your image file path, file name typo etc.

Comment: It is false, but I can't figure out why. My file path seems to be correct.

Comment: `at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)` seems to suggest otherwise

Comment: Try a different image.  Also try using forward slashes.  I think that works in java.  C:/Projects/Test/...

Comment: And try a shorter path, like an image sitting in C:/Projects

Comment: @EthanJCRubik let's do this step-by-step:

  1. move your image file into `C:\\Projects` as you already suggested. Try after this my 2 lines of code.
  2. if problem isn't in the path try rename you image to e.g. `a.jpg` and try my 2 lines of code again.
  3. let us know :)

Comment: I can't move an image file into projects, the best I can do is move it into projects/test.

Comment: It returns false, even when I do this:

Comment: `File f = new File("C:\\Projects\\Test\\a.jpg");
    boolean value = f.canRead();
    System.out.println(value);`

Comment: @EthanJCRubik try to move `a.jpg` into `C:\\Projects` or in any another folder. It's only for your troubleshooting for getting `value == true`. Later, after full problem understanding, we'll think how fix it (locate your picture) better. BTW can you share somehow your code? E.g. at GitHub?

Comment: My mouse turns into a little x symbol when I try to drag the file into projects. I literally can't do it. I can only share my code on stackoverflow.

Comment: I finally got it to return true by creating a new folder called graphics, and then doing this:  `File f = new File("graphics/a.jpg");
boolean value = f.canRead();
System.out.println(value);`

Comment: But here's the problem: now that I have the image stored as a bufferedImage, it still isn't showing up on my JPane.

Comment: "How do I properly create a BufferedImage from file?" that s your answer dude; give the points and move on

Comment: Nevermind, I just hadn't scaled the image properly. Thanks for all your help! (I would vote up your answer, but I just lost 2 reputation for this question being downvoted, and I can't upvote anymore.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to read the file from the classpath instead.

```
final BufferedImage defaultImage =
    ImageIO.read(
        this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/graphics/file.png"));
```

Place the file in src/main/resource/graphics. (for maven defaults)